# How to parse yahoo finance stock price using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

For the learning purpose, I tried to extract the current stock price of AAPL using yahoo finance.
However, I am getting empty outputs.

**How to extract the stock value?**

Required value: 134.69 (as shown in image below) (note this value changes with time, but this is just an example)

## MWE

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


ticker = 'aapl'
url = f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{ticker.upper()}"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

soup.find_all("div", class_="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)")
```

## Inspect

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT (13.06.2023): Updated to working version**

To get current quote you can use next example (don't forget to set `User-Agent` HTTP header to get right response from the server):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0'}

ticker = "AAPL"
url = f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{ticker}"

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

current = soup.select_one(f'fin-streamer[data-field="regularMarketPrice"][data-symbol="{ticker}"]')
print(current['value'])
```

Prints:

```
183.79
```

Comment: How to get only the number 134.36?